# React "npm ERR! missing script: start" when running project with Docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I get the error mentioned in the title when running my docker compose, I have no idea why. I've been at it for hours, literally nothing helps.

I'm following this [guide](https://github.com/docker/awesome-compose/tree/master/react-java-mysql)

Folder structure:

[image: Folder structure]

Dockerfile:

```
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM node:lts AS development

WORKDIR /code
COPY package.json /code/package.json
COPY package-lock.json /code/package-lock.json

RUN npm ci
COPY . /code

ENV CI=false
ENV PORT=3000

# CMD [ "npm", "start" ]

FROM development AS dev-envs
RUN <<EOF
apt-get update
apt-get install -y git
EOF

RUN <<EOF
useradd -s /bin/bash -m vscode
groupadd docker
usermod -aG docker vscode
EOF
# install Docker tools (cli, buildx, compose)
COPY --from=gloursdocker/docker / /
# CMD [ "npm", "start" ]

FROM development AS build

RUN ["npm", "run", "build"]

FROM nginx:1.13-alpine

COPY --from=build /code/build /usr/share/nginx/html

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

compose.yaml

```
services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./tracker
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=example
    networks:
      - spring-postgres
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    secrets:
      - db-password
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - spring-postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=example
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/db-password
    expose:
      - 5432

  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./tracker_frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - /project/node_modules
    networks:
      - react-spring
    depends_on:
      - backend
    expose:
      - 3306
      - 33060

volumes:
  db-data:

secrets:
  db-password:
    file: db/password.txt

networks:
  react-spring:
  spring-postgres:
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "tracker_frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@atlaskit/inline-edit": "^12.2.12",
    "@atlaskit/textarea": "^4.5.6",
    "@atlaskit/textfield": "^5.3.7",
    "@atlaskit/theme": "^12.4.1",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.3",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "jquery": "^3.6.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.2",
    "react-data-table-component": "^7.5.3",
    "react-data-table-component-with-filter": "^7.5.3",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^14.2.3",
    "react-icons": "^4.8.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-select": "^5.7.3",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.9",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Tried a ton of things I found online, like replacing the package.json's `"start": "react-scripts start"` with `"start": node index.js`, trying out a bunch of other Dockerfiles, double-checking everything, but I've been at this for 6+ hours now and I'm completely out of ideas.

I'm a beginner when it comes to Docker, admittedly I don't know much about it, but I got the backend + DB to be containerized, and they are running fine, but I'm at a complete loss at this error I keep getting. Literally nothing works provided by people at different questions similar to mine.

Edit 1:

Longer error log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/local/bin/node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.18
3 info using node@v14.21.3
4 verbose stack Error: missing script: start
4 verbose stack     at run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/run-script.js:155:19)
4 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/run-script.js:63:5
4 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:111:5
4 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:431:5
4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:386:45)
4 verbose stack     at final (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:429:3)
4 verbose stack     at then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:156:5)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:345:20)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:123:16)
4 verbose stack     at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:282:13)
5 verbose cwd /app
6 verbose Linux 5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2
7 verbose argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
8 verbose node v14.21.3
9 verbose npm  v6.14.18
10 error missing script: start
11 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Edit 2:

changed

`ENV CI=true` to `ENV CI=false`
`RUN npm ci` to `RUN npm ci --legacy-peer-deps`

Edit 3:

added `CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]` to the end of my Dockerfile

Comment: as you are running `nginx` you don't need to run `npm start`, the `build` will create the `final html and the js` files and they will be served by `nginx`. So comment `CMD [ "npm", "start" ]` and try

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but it wasn't that, I've updated the post with the commented out `CMD [ "npm", "start" ]`, but still getting the exact same error, also included the longer error log if it's of any help.

Comment: Will run into same error if you  run `docker build -t test:1.0 .` in tracker_frontend folder ?

Comment: I ran into a different error when running `docker build -t test:1.0 .` that I fixed with my Edit 2 changes, running `docker build -t test:1.0 .` in the tracker_frontend folder now completes without any errors, but `docker compose up -d` in the main folder where the compose file is, runs into the same error as before... I'm so tired of this...

Answer (score 1):

Very weird behavior, adding `CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]` in my Edit 3 alone did not solve my problem, but I deleted every image, every container, every volume, and for some reason it runs without any problems right now. So to summarize:

1. Deleted every container, image, volume in my docker that had anything to do with my project
2. I ran `docker-compose build --no-cache`
3. Then I ran `docker-compose up -d` and it worked

Edited the Dockerfile in the original post so now that it reflects my current state